# How can I make the content go under the sidebar

Tags: html, css

[image]

http://img818.imageshack.us/img818/575/14394211.png

How can I make the content go under the sidebar? So far my attempts have been unsuccessfull.

Comment: Show the code you have so far.

Comment: You want to recreate that image in HTML/CSS, or does the image show the *problem* you're having..?

Comment: I need to recreate all of that using html and css, but I can't achive to have the content under the sidebar..I will post the code one sec.

Comment: 'under' as in ['behind' the sidebar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8553148/82548), or as in ['below the lower edge of the sidebar](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GNkrQ/1/)? Can you show an image of what you *want* it to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you need. Please check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YT8YR/1/

You can also find the CSS usage there.

Comment: By 'under' i think what he meant is 'below'. Also as per the screen he gave, i believe 'below' is what he is looking for.

Comment: -1, unless the OP want's the sidebar to resize with the viewport size (30%).  William Van Rensselaer has the best answer.

Comment: @JohnB - That's a silly reason to downvote an answer; it was a demonstration, not a literal implementation. *You* don't know either, and the OP has marked this as accepted.

Comment: @Jared Farrish - the OP just doesn't realize this yet, my comment was meant to help him :)  Sidebars are often used for menus or ads, thus a width re-sizing sidebar is rarely useful.

Comment: @JohnB - That has little bearing on whether the answer demonstrated the effect the OP was looking for, which *has nothing to do* with whether the div's expand/contract on screen size.

Answer (score 4):

Add `float:right;` to the sidebar.

```
#header {
    height: 100px;
}

#sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Example: [http://jsfiddle.net/qzCJZ/](http://jsfiddle.net/qzCJZ/1/)

Comment: Really? What problem do you think he's having that would be solved with that?

Comment: @David Thomas: It's called a stab in the dark ;)

Comment: That's a bizarre demo/fiddle. And I [don't think it's working](http://jsfiddle.net/qzCJZ/2/). (Unless of course by under the OP means wrap around the sidebar... Hmm.)

Comment: @JaredFarrish From the image, it looks like the OP means for the content to wrap around the sidebar. Also from his wording, he said "under" not "behind". :)

Comment: There is some ambiguousness in interpreting those two terms, especially in the absence of one. `;)` Of course I jumped to the wrong conclusion, but that's how it goes sometimes. And that fiddle was odd without a content div.

Comment: The picture is not ambiguous!

Comment: @JohnB - You are correct. Note, I said *terms*. For all I knew, that was a demonstration of what the OP *currently* had and wanted the content under the sidebar. I believe I was not the only one who guessed wrong. `;)`